# xlsx-template array of objects are not reflecting

Tags: node.js, xlsx

I have json containing array of objects. I am trying to replace it in xlsx template using node.js package xlsx-template but it's only generating 1 row means only reflecting 1 object instead of multiple objects on multiple rows. Here is my json and code:
JSON:

```
[
  {
    branchName: 'Johar Branch',
    totalBilled: 10,
    collectionTillDueDate: 10,
    collectionTillExpiryDate: 0,
    branchId: 63ac043737cc70001139e1a0,
    month: 'February',
    collectionTillDueDatePercentage: 100,
    collectionTillExpiryPercentage: 0
  },
  {
    branchName: 'Johar Branch',
    totalBilled: 15,
    collectionTillDueDate: 15,
    collectionTillExpiryDate: 0,
    branchId: 63ac043737cc70001139e1a0,
    month: 'June',
    collectionTillDueDatePercentage: 100,
    collectionTillExpiryPercentage: 0
  }
]
```

And code i am using:

```
const data = fs.readFileSync(templatePath);
    let template = new XlsxTemplate(data);


    invoices.forEach((item) => {
        template.substitute(1, item);
    })

    const xls = template.generate();
```

Help needed.

I have tried multiple solutions but not worked.